# How many bytes does this String have?

Tags: java, string, byte

I have this `String`, but they said that I have to convert the last 3 bytes of it, to 6 byte string...
So, how can I do it on JAVA, How do I know where the last 3 bytes start?, I'm sorry but seriously I have no idea about it.

> 742da831d2b657fa53d347301ec610e1ebf8a3d0

They said that the conversion should be

> SpeedTouch

And then if I convert the first 5 bytes of

> SpeedTouchF8A3D0

To a 10 byte string

At the end I'll get

> 742DA831D2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without context, it's just hard to understand your question.

The last 3 bytes of the hash “742da831d2b657fa53d347301ec610e1ebf8a3d0” you give are “f8a3d0”, which are the last 6 characters “F8A3D0” in “SpeedTouchF8A3D0”.

The first 5 bytes of the hash “742da831d2b657fa53d347301ec610e1ebf8a3d0” are “742da831d2”, which gives the 10-character string you are referring to: “742DA831D2”.

Comment: Really? thats all? OMG Sorry i'm so stupid the maybe when i try to translate from english to Spanish (My native language) there was the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this --  Convert given String to byte

byte[] b = string.getBytes();

byte[] b = string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

Then perform your opertations on byte[]

Comment: ok thanks, but now what does "6 byte string" mean?  i can understand i have to make 3 bytes to 6 but how? :S